# Email validation fails on HELO / RCPT TO commands to records

Tags: email, smtp, mx-record, limitations

I'm migrating a mailing service from a server to another.
Before setting up new mailing list I wanted to process it through an email validtor I've setting up on the server.

I basically used this tool ([Mass email validation](http://git.zionetrix.net/mass_validate_email?a=viewblob&p=mass_validate_email&h=4aa9e9c065b7ebf864adc79e1efb6c6fdbb72570&f=mass_validate_email.py)) that works in 3 steps :

- syntaxic validation
- domain name validation (MX record)
- `HELO` and `RCPT TO` commansd (SMTP protocol) to simulate a mail-send to the address that grants the address in particular in reachable

After a couple of tests I realised that there was issues with this validtion method. I tried running the process twice on the same initial batch and the results were different.

I noticed that addresses with very common domain like `gmail.com`, `hotmail.com` would tend to fail at the third step, especially at the end of the batches.

It seems like those servers simply block my requests systematically after a certain amount of requests, like my server becomes blacklisted.

If I wait a few hours before starting a new batch, emails that have failed previously will be correctly validated, like there was a cap limitation to the number of requests in a given time period.

Is there some "official guideline" about email validation to avoid such problems ?